# MySQL query giving 5% bonus to employee whose salary is less than average salary

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a beginner in MySQL. I have a table named **Employee** and have a column **Salary**. I'm trying to give 5% bonus to employee table whose salary is below average salary. I don't know where i did mistakes. Can anyone tell me where's the wrong?

**I tried this SQL:**
update employee 
set salary = salary * 1.05
where salary < (select avg(salary) from employee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql has this weird *feature* for UPDATE statements and you can't directly refer to the updated table, so you need to nest the subquery inside another:

```
update employee 
set salary = salary * 1.05 
where salary < (select salary from (select avg(salary) salary from employee) t )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get around this error using a join:

```
UPDATE employee e1
INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary FROM employee) e2
SET salary = 1.05 * salary
WHERE salary > avg_salary;
```